# Perl SHA-256 algorithm generates output different from the equivalent Java

Tags: java, perl, sha256

I have the following Java code:

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        byte[] salt = {
             84,  65,  -51,  83,   -4,  -17,  -32,  61,
            -26,  33, -106, -81,  -14,   70,  -30,  59,
             41, -19,   -1,  19, -104, -100,  -31,  31,
             57,  -6, -115, -99,    0,   38, -123, -11
        };

        byte[] password = { 100, 112, 107, 57, 52, 110, 50 };

        try {

            MessageDigest messageDigest;

            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

            messageDigest.reset();
            messageDigest.update(salt);

            byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(password);

            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                messageDigest.reset();
                hash = messageDigest.digest(hash);
            }

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(hash.length * 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(Character.forDigit(hash[i] >> 4 & 0xF, 16));
                stringBuffer.append(Character.forDigit(hash[i] & 0xF, 16));
            }

            System.out.println("HashArray: " + Arrays.toString(hash));
            System.out.println("HashString: " + stringBuffer.toString());
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
HashArray: [-127, -38, -46, -2, 51, -2, -83, -42, 3, 83, -78, -72, -115, -28, 108, 58, -76, -35, -13, 33, 63, -96, 104, 101, -76, 23, 102, -28, -60, 4, 85, 82]
```

and

```
HashString: 81dad2fe33feadd60353b2b88de46c3ab4ddf3213fa06865b41766e4c4045552
```

I tried to translate the Java code to Perl, but I have a understanding problem. In Java, I use two arrays to generate the hash. If I use the same arrays in Perl, I don't get the same result.

Here is my Perl code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::SHA 'sha256';

my @salt = (
     "84",  "65",  -"51",  "83",   "-4",  "-17",  "-32",  "61",
    "-26",  "33", "-106", "-81",  "-14",   "70",  "-30",  "59",
     "41", "-19",   "-1",  "19", "-104", "-100",  "-31",  "31",
     "57",  "-6", "-115", "-99",    "0",   "38", "-123", "-11"
);

my @password = ( "100", "112", "107", "57", "52", "110", "50" );

my $alg = 256;
my $sha = Digest::SHA->new($alg);

$sha->add(@salt);
$sha->add(@password);

for ( my $i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++ ) {
    $sha->add(@password)
}

my $output = $sha->hexdigest;
print "\nHash: $output\n";
```

Output is

```
Hash: 3883ae8f7438cc7e8fac86d25aa5789c4434294a70ea13d5e8f547fc7a8e45c2
```

Can someone explain how to get the Perl code to produce the same output as the Java?

Comment: `-"51"` is that similar to `"-51"` ?

Comment: I don't know perl but the minus sign of the 3rd element of salt is not between the quotes

Comment: You're hashing completely different values (bytes versus strings of characters), and in different ways. Of course the two are going to be different.

Comment: It gives the same result if you remove all quotes from the numbers.

Comment: @RobAu "-51" is correct

Comment: @chroba the " makes no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The Java version works with bytes, the Perl version with strings of digits. Use [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) to convert the strings to their byte equivalents.
2. In the Java version, you are applying the hash to the hash computed so far, in the Perl code, you just hash the same value again and again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Digest::SHA 'sha256';

my @salt = (84, 65, -51, 83, -4, -17, -32, 61, -26, 33, -106, -81,
            -14, 70, -30, 59, 41, -19, -1, 19, -104, -100, -31, 31,
            57, -6, -115, -99, 0, 38, -123, -11);

my @password = (100, 112, 107, 57, 52, 110, 50);

my $alg = 256;
my $sha = Digest::SHA->new($alg);

$sha->add(pack 'c*', @salt);
$sha->add(pack 'c*', @password);

$sha->add($sha->digest) for 1 .. 999;

my $output = $sha->hexdigest;
print "\nHash: $output\n";
```